# I/O error, cant implement file on listbox

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

I wrote this code, and the console makes an error, I tried couple of ways I couldn't fix it, can you please explain where is my mistake. Thank You

```
import os
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Umer Selmani\Desktop\prog.practice\MP1")

import csv


with open('FoodDB.csv','r') as FDB:
    file = csv.reader(FDB)
    for line in file:
        print(line)

from tkinter import *

class Diet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Left = Frame(root,width= 250,height=200,bg='salmon')
        self.Left.pack(side=LEFT,pady=5)

        self.labelrdL=Label(self.Left, text="Food Menu").grid(row=0)
        self.listboxrdL=Listbox(self.Left,width=30).grid(row=1)
        for q in file:
            self.listboxrdL.insert(END,q)
        self.buttonrdL=Button(self.Left, text="Continue",bg="red").grid(row=2)

root = Tk()
diet = Diet()   # Create an instance of Diet.
root.mainloop()
```

and here you have the error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Umer Selmani/.PyCharmEdu2018.2/config/scratches/scratch_3.py", line 26, in <module>
    diet = Diet()   # Create an instance of Diet.
  File "C:/Users/Umer Selmani/.PyCharmEdu2018.2/config/scratches/scratch_3.py", line 21, in __init__
    for q in file:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you need to work on here.

You should follow the PEP8 guidelines for naming your variables. Define all of your imports at the start of the file. Last and most important here you should use your `with open` statement when updating the list box. Keep in mind that `with open` apposed to `open` will automatically close the file after the `with` statement concludes.

Additionally this line here `self.listboxrdL = Listbox(self.Left,width=30).grid(row=1)` will prevent you from adding information to the listbox.

Make sure you use the geometry manager on a new line to prevent issues by doing this:

```
self.listboxrdL = Listbox(self.Left,width=30)
self.listboxrdL.grid(row=1)
```

Code:

```
import os
import csv
import tkinter as tk
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Umer Selmani\Desktop\prog.practice\MP1")

class Diet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.left = tk.Frame(root, width=250, height=200, bg='salmon')
        self.left.pack(side="left", pady=5)

        tk.Label(self.left, text="Food Menu").grid(row=0)
        self.listbox_rdl = tk.Listbox(self.left, width=30)
        self.listbox_rdl.grid(row=1)

        with open('FoodDB.csv', 'r') as fdb:
            file = csv.reader(fdb)
            for q in file:
                self.listbox_rdl.insert("end", q)

        tk.Button(self.left, text="Continue", bg="red").grid(row=2)

root = tk.Tk()
diet = Diet()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your 'with open' closes the file automatically. Hence, you get the error.

Instead of `with open('FoodDB.csv','r') as FDB:` try `FDB = open('FoodDB.csv','r')`

Don't forget to close the file manually once you are done.

```
FDB.close()
```

Full solution should be something like below:

```
import os
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Umer Selmani\Desktop\prog.practice\MP1")

import csv


FDB = open('FoodDB.csv','r')
file = csv.reader(FDB)
#for line in file:
   #print(line)

from tkinter import *

class Diet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Left = Frame(root,width= 250,height=200,bg='salmon')
        self.Left.pack(side=LEFT,pady=5)

        self.labelrdL=Label(self.Left, text="Food Menu").grid(row=0)
        self.listboxrdL=Listbox(self.Left,width=30).grid(row=1)
        for q in file:
            self.listboxrdL.insert(END,q)
        self.buttonrdL=Button(self.Left, text="Continue",bg="red").grid(row=2)

root = Tk()
diet = Diet()   # Create an instance of Diet.
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Normal read works, but instead of with statement open the file directly as per my answer above. Let me know how it goes. Don't have all packages in my machine, couldn't test it.

Comment: thank you fam, but there are no items in listbox :(?

Comment: I think, that is because you already read everything from the file. Remove or comment out the for loop and the print lines at the beginning and see if it changes anything.

Comment: Modified the answer i.e. commented out two lines to skip reading the contents of file at the start of the file.

Comment: Personally I would use the with open statement directly with the `for q in file` loop.